# gem for translating ruby I18n strings on rails app from the browser/frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, i18n-gem

**Is there an up2date gem out to edit the whole rails i18n strings from the frontend? and to edit your translations from the webbrowser?**

There once was this great gem:

- https://github.com/archan937/e9s-demo
- screencast: http://vimeo.com/17050431

Which let you edit your translations from the webbrowser. 
Is there any solution out today that does the same or better?

Answer (score 1):

[Copycopte](https://github.com/copycopter)r might be useful,

I have my custom made solution,i migrate I18n to redis and set backend to redis,and added  one Ui that list down all the I18n and you can edit or delete or create,

I have written small library that will migrate to yaml to redis https://github.com/amardaxini/i18n_redis

Comment: thx for posting nice project but this is more a copywriter solution to manage content, not to manage translations of I18n content

Answer (score 1):

We had some bad experiences with Copycopter, since it can mess up your localization files pretty badly. Thats's why we have built our own solution: [PhraseApp](https://phraseapp.com)

And we have pushed even further by allowing you to edit your translations on the page itself and not only with a generic form. If you have decided to use Copycopter instead, [we provide a simple migration guide](https://phraseapp.com/docs/migration-guides/migrating-from-copycopter) how move the data to PhraseApp.

Comment: great solution but way to expensive for non profit personal project. by any change you could opensource the basic functionality of frontend translation? Currently using locale app but not really nice either.

Comment: PhraseApp is free for open source projects, so you can definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/jhilden/i18n_viz now thats does exactly what you are looking for. It supports Rails 3+.